# The property 'Content' is set more than once Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I added ContentView xaml file in xamarin.forms project, but it showing annoying warning

> The property 'Content' is set more than once.

Below my ContentView.xaml file

```
<ContentView
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="XamarinTestList.View.AddContect">>
<StackLayout Spacing="12">
    <Entry x:Name="txtContactName" Text="{Binding Name}" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="White" Placeholder="Contact Name" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <Entry  x:Name="txtMobileNumber" Keyboard="Telephone" Text="{Binding MobileNumber}" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="40" Placeholder="Mobile Number" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Entry x:Name="txtAge" Text="{Binding Age}" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="White" Placeholder="Age" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <Picker x:Name="GenderPicker" SelectedItem="{Binding Gender}" Title="Gender" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Male</x:String>
                    <x:String>FeMale</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
        </Picker>
    </StackLayout>
    <DatePicker x:Name="txtDOB" Date="{Binding DOB}" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <Entry x:Name="txtAddress" Text="{Binding Address}" BackgroundColor="White"  HeightRequest="40" Placeholder="Address"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Warning screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is the `>>` at the beginning tag of the `ContentView` only in your question or also real code?

Comment: This is only real code.. It got solved thank you.

Comment: Good it's figured out so fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe because your ContentView has two '>' at the end?